# loop with more than one item at a time

Tags: bash, shell, unix, xargs

We can iterate over a set of items, considering one at a time, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( ls ); do
    echo item: $i
done
```

How can we process several items at a time in a similar loop? Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i,j,k in $( ls ); do
    echo item i: $i
    echo item j: $j
    echo item k: $k
done
```

That second shell script is incorrect but should give an accurate illustration of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't use `ls` like this: use `for i in *; do` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If filenames does not contain spaces:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | xargs -L 3 | while read i j k; do
  echo item i: $i
  echo item j: $j
  echo item k: $k
done
```

**Edit:**

I removed `-print0` and `-0`.

Comment: Actually, to be *absolutely* safe, you do need the `-print0`, as well as *3* properly constructed calls to `read`.

Comment: I think the `-print0` and `-0` options could help with filenames containing whitespace.

Comment: @SzG but only when the read read's them as null terminated. Otherwise, it is pointless. And you can't read (with `read`) null terminated when using `xargs`... So, `-print0` and proper `read` or `-print|xargs`... not both.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't have *too* many items (although the shell should be able to
handle quite a few positional arguments.

```
# Save the original positional arguments, if you need them
original_pp=( "$@" )
set -- *
while (( $# > 0 )); do
    i=$1 j=$2 k=$3     # Optional; you can use $1, $2, $3 directly
    ...
    shift 3 || shift $#   # In case there are fewer than 3 arguments left
done

# Restore positional arguments, if necessary/desired
set -- "${original_pp[@]}"
```

For POSIX compatibility, use `[ "$#" -gt 0 ]` instead of the `((...))` expression. There's no easy way to save and restore all the positional parameters in a POSIX-compatible way. (Unless there is a character you can use to concatenate them unambiguously into a single string.)

Here is the subshell jm666 mentions:

```
(
    set -- *
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
        i=$1 j=$2 k=$3
        ...
        shift 3 || shift $#
    done
)
```

Any changes to parameters you set inside the subshell will be lost once the subshell exits, but the above code is otherwise POSIX-compatible.

Comment: You could use a subshell, as long as you don't need to set any parameters that will be needed later.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late answer, I would do this with non-spectacular way :), like:

```
while read -r -d $'\0' f1
do
        read -r -d $'\0' f2
        read -r -d $'\0' f3

        echo "==$f1==$f2==$f3=="

done < <(find test/ ... findargs... -print0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `to get n items a time from the list` I think you want to get `n` items from an array.

Use it like this:

```
n=3
arr=(a b c d e)

echo "${arr[@]:0:$n}"
a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another solution in a typical programming manner ->

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
arr=(*) #read the files/dirs in an array
total=${#arr[@]} #get the array size
count=0;
#loop it thru in multiples of three
while [ $count -lt $((total-2)) ]
do
        echo "i is ${arr[$count]}"
        echo "j is ${arr[$((count+1))]}"
        echo "k is ${arr[$((count+2))]}"
        count=$((count+3))
done
#print the remaining element(s)
rem=$((total%3));    
if [ $rem -eq 1 ];
then
        echo "i is ${arr[$total-1]}"
elif [ $rem -eq 2 ];
then
        echo "i is ${arr[$total-2]}"
        echo "j is ${arr[$total-1]}"
fi
echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel you can run:

```
ls | parallel -N3 "echo item i: {1}; echo item j: {2}; echo item k: {3}"
```

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: I don't think running random code from the internet (even more so if it is over plain http, not https) is a good advice. (And yes, I'm talking about this "installer", not the installed software.)

Comment: That is in general good advice: It is preferable to install through a path that secured through digital signatures (such as apt). But some people do not have that luxury: Maybe they do not have root access, maybe they use a distribution for which GNU Parallel is not packaged. For these people it will not make any difference securitywise whether they run the installer directly from the internet or they run the installed program: Either of these could contain a backdoor.

Comment: At least provide a https URL for the installer, so if they (rightly) trust your site (and its certificate), they won't get a version which is replaced by a MitM attacker.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `xargs`, `awk`, `sed` or `paste` to restructure your input.

```
job_select()
{
  ls
}

job_process()
{
  while read i j k; do
    printf 'item i: %s\nitem j: %s\nitem k: %s\n' "$i" "$j" "$k"
  done
}

job_restructure_xargs()
{
  xargs -L 3
}

job_rstructure_awk()
{
  awk '(NR % 3 == 1) { i = $0 } (NR % 3 == 2) { j = $0 } (NR % 3 == 0){ k = $0; print(i,j,k)}'
}

job_restructure_sed()
{
  sed -e 'N;N;s/\n/ /g'
}

job_restructure_paste()
{
  paste - - -
}
```

Then any of the combinations

```
job_select | job_restructure_xargs | job_process
job_select | job_restructure_awk | job_process
job_select | job_restructure_sed | job_process
job_select | job_restructure_paste | job_process
```

does what you want.

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`, especially not in such a Rube-Goldberg-esque framework. This will not work for filenames containing whitespace.

Comment: I just assumed it was as safe to parse `ls` output as the OP assumed it.  In shell programming, data processing is performed by filters, so there is nothing like Rube-Goldberg here, just regular shell programming.  That said, your answer is far superior!

Comment: I take back the Rube Goldberg comment; I didn't look closely enough, and didn't notice your three `job_restructure_*` functions were just 3 alternate implementations of the same task. However, it's best to squash the urge to parse `ls` wherever it crops up.